# Tables - Formatting rows to have no breaks in delimited rows width and font size

Tags: tables, formatting

I've started studying LaTeX recently and I have a doubt. I'm getting the table in the figure below for a job and I'd like to let the last row (of averages) more presentable (without the breaks for example). It's possible?

My code is below the image.

Obs. The maximum table width can be 8.55cm and the column width can be variable. It can be breaks in the legends (if not, will be better, but is not a requirement). The font size can satisfy this requirement "Use font 10 regular for Table caption, 1st letter, and font 8 regular for the rest of table caption and table legend".

Thanks!

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
      \footnotesize \onehalfspacing
      \caption{Table caption}
      \begin{tabular}{p{0.4cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}}
         \hline
         \normalfont N & Metric1 (\%) & Metric2 (\%) & Metric3 (Hz) & Metric4 & Metric5 \\
         \hline
            1 & 93.55 & 10.79 & 4.19 & -1.05 & 8.22 \\
            2 & 96.53 & 25.91 & 2.72 & 3.13 & 16.16 \\
            3 & 93.13 & 17.34 & 3.98 & 1.65 & 16.85 \\
            4 & 90.44 & 24.20 & 4.87 & -1.49 & 5.44 \\
            5 & 93.23 & 18.67 & 3.14 & 1.83 & 14.55 \\
            6 & 91.16 & 25.44 & 3.89 & 0.77 & 7.04 \\
            7 & 91.54 & 28.41 & 4.18 & 3.36 & 18.99 \\
            8 & 96.03 & 32.06 & 2.79 & 1.93 & 4.66 \\
            9 & 93.97 & 19.92 & 3.46 & 1.64 & 9.31 \\
            10 & 91.55 & 32.16 & 4.14 & 2.52 & 7.72 \\
            11 & 90.80 & 40.47 & 3.16 & 1.00 & 3.78 \\
            12 & 91.52 & 67.09 & 2.88 & 5.85 & 50.38 \\
            13 & 90.25 & 37.93 & 3.76 & 3.30 & 17.84 \\
         \hline
            Avg & $92.59\pm1.10$ & $29.26\pm7.66$ & $3.63\pm0.36$ & $1.88\pm1.04$ & $13.92\pm6.63$ \\
         \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \label{table2}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome. // It's always better to start your code with ` documentclass ...` and provide all that's needed to run, when copied, and still showing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've indicated that the table's width must not exceed 8.55cm, I suggest you switch from a `tabular` environment to a `tabular*` environment and set its overall width to 8.55cm.

I would also employ the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type to align the numbers in the data columns on their respective decimal markers, and I would employ the macros of the `booktabs` package to draw well-space horizontal lines. Imposing a bit of structure on the header material and on providing some visual grouping (such as insering a bit of extra whitespace after the 5th and 10th rows) would also appear to be ideas worth exploring.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Table caption\strut}\label{table2}
% make LaTeX figure out amount of intercolumn whitespace:
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\begin{tabular*}{8.55cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} % width: 8.55cm
    T{2.0} T{2.2} T{2.2} T{2.2} T{-1.2} T{2.2} }
\toprule
{N} & {Metric1} & {Metric2} & {Metric3} & {Metric4} & {Metric5} \\
    & {(\%)}    & {(\%)}    & {(Hz)} \\
\midrule
             1 & 93.55 & 10.79 & 4.19 & -1.05 &  8.22 \\
             2 & 96.53 & 25.91 & 2.72 &  3.13 & 16.16 \\
             3 & 93.13 & 17.34 & 3.98 &  1.65 & 16.85 \\
             4 & 90.44 & 24.20 & 4.87 & -1.49 &  5.44 \\
             5 & 93.23 & 18.67 & 3.14 &  1.83 & 14.55 \\
             \addlinespace
             6 & 91.16 & 25.44 & 3.89 &  0.77 &  7.04 \\
             7 & 91.54 & 28.41 & 4.18 &  3.36 & 18.99 \\
             8 & 96.03 & 32.06 & 2.79 &  1.93 &  4.66 \\
             9 & 93.97 & 19.92 & 3.46 &  1.64 &  9.31 \\
            10 & 91.55 & 32.16 & 4.14 &  2.52 &  7.72 \\
            \addlinespace
            11 & 90.80 & 40.47 & 3.16 &  1.00 &  3.78 \\
            12 & 91.52 & 67.09 & 2.88 &  5.85 & 50.38 \\
            13 & 90.25 & 37.93 & 3.76 &  3.30 & 17.84 \\
\midrule
{Avg} & 92.59 &   29.26 &    3.63 &    1.88 &   13.92 \\
    & \pm1.10 & \pm7.66 & \pm0.36 & \pm1.04 & \pm6.63 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico, the `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` and `{tabular*}{8.55cm}...` made all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient that you change all the `p{1.1cm}` in `p{1.5cm}` and reduce some space so you have what you want (total width= 7.9 cm):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \footnotesize %\onehalfspacing
        \caption{Table caption}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.4cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
            \hline
            \normalfont N & Metric1 (\%) & Metric2 (\%) & Metric3 (Hz) & Metric4 & Metric5 \\
            \hline
            1 & 93.55 & 10.79 & 4.19 & -1.05 & 8.22 \\
            2 & 96.53 & 25.91 & 2.72 & 3.13 & 16.16 \\
            3 & 93.13 & 17.34 & 3.98 & 1.65 & 16.85 \\
            4 & 90.44 & 24.20 & 4.87 & -1.49 & 5.44 \\
            5 & 93.23 & 18.67 & 3.14 & 1.83 & 14.55 \\
            6 & 91.16 & 25.44 & 3.89 & 0.77 & 7.04 \\
            7 & 91.54 & 28.41 & 4.18 & 3.36 & 18.99 \\
            8 & 96.03 & 32.06 & 2.79 & 1.93 & 4.66 \\
            9 & 93.97 & 19.92 & 3.46 & 1.64 & 9.31 \\
            10 & 91.55 & 32.16 & 4.14 & 2.52 & 7.72 \\
            11 & 90.80 & 40.47 & 3.16 & 1.00 & 3.78 \\
            12 & 91.52 & 67.09 & 2.88 & 5.85 & 50.38 \\
            13 & 90.25 & 37.93 & 3.76 & 3.30 & 17.84 \\
            \hline
            Avg & $92.59\!\pm\!1.10\!$ & $29.26\!\pm\!7.66$ & $3.63\!\pm\!0.36$ & $1.88\!\pm\!1.04\!$ & $13.92\!\pm\!6.63$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table2}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: The OP has indicated that the maximal column width must be less than or equal to 8.55cm. In your solution, the sum of the *usable* widths of the 5 data columns alone comes to 8cm.

Answer (score 0):

At writing of your table I would use `siunitx` package for `S` columns (in which numbers are aligned at decimal points) and `booktabs` for table horizontal rules and `makecell˛(for column headers).

**Edit:**
I overlooked demand that table width should less or equal to 8.55 cm.  This require, that table's font should be `\footnotesize`, then removing column separations at beginning  and end of table and use `tight-spacing` options for `S` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
\caption{Table caption}
\label{table2}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         tight-spacing}      % <---   
    \begin{tabular}{@{} r *{2}{S[table-format=2.2(3)]}
                          *{3}{S[table-format=1.2(3)]}
                    @{} }
    \toprule
N   & {\makecell{Metric1\\ (\%)}} 
           & {\makecell{Metric2\\ (\%)}} 
                   & {\makecell{Metric3\\ (Hz)}}
                          & {\makecell{Metric4}}
                                  & {\makecell{Metric5}} \\
    \midrule
 1  & 93.55 & 10.79 & 4.19  & -1.05 &  8.22 \\
 2  & 96.53 & 25.91 & 2.72  &  3.13 & 16.16 \\
 3  & 93.13 & 17.34 & 3.98  &  1.65 & 16.85 \\
 4  & 90.44 & 24.20 & 4.87  & -1.49 &  5.44 \\
 5  & 93.23 & 18.67 & 3.14  &  1.83 & 14.55 \\
 6  & 91.16 & 25.44 & 3.89  &  0.77 &  7.04 \\
 7  & 91.54 & 28.41 & 4.18  &  3.36 & 18.99 \\
 8  & 96.03 & 32.06 & 2.79  &  1.93 &  4.66 \\
 9  & 93.97 & 19.92 & 3.46  &  1.64 &  9.31 \\
10  & 91.55 & 32.16 & 4.14  &  2.52 &  7.72 \\
11  & 90.80 & 40.47 & 3.16  &  1.00 &  3.78 \\
12  & 91.52 & 67.09 & 2.88  &  5.85 & 50.38 \\
13  & 90.25 & 37.93 & 3.76  &  3.30 & 17.84 \\
    \midrule
 Avg 
    & 92.59(110)
           & 29.26(766)
                   & 3.63(036) 
                          & 1.88(104)
                                  & 13.92(663)    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Table width is now les than 8.55cm.

Comment: Have you ascertained that this table's width doesn't exceed 8.55cm?

Comment: @Mico, i just realized this and correct my answer. Now table width is about 8.53cm ...

Comment: Thanks, @Zarko for the solution! It almost solved the entire problem. In my document the width was a little bigger than 8.55cm. Morover, smth gone wrong with the cells of column Metric4 where there was the minus sign and the cells of column Metric 5 where the integer part was higher than 9. I've solved using the `table-format`. Anyway, thank you!